# Angular 2 how to access headers

Tags: javascript, angular, https, header

I need to get Set-Cookie from my Response Headers. My response looks like this: 
[image]

My code looks like this:

```
this.http.get(url, {headers: this.getHeaders(token)})
        .timeout(this.timeout - this.loginTimeout)
        .subscribe(res => {
            var payload = res.json();
            var headers = res.headers;
            var setCookieHeader = headers.get('Set-Cookie');
            console.log(setCookieHeader);
```

But setCookieHeader is always null. Is there any way how to access this response Headers? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I think you need to upgrade to the latest `http` that coming with `angular 4.3+` by `import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';` and `imports: [ HttpClientModule ]` in your `@NgModule`

Then you can refer to https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response

```
http
  .get<MyJsonData>('/data.json', {observe: 'response'})
  .subscribe(resp => {
    // Here, resp is of type HttpResponse<MyJsonData>.
    // You can inspect its headers:
    console.log(resp.headers.get('X-Custom-Header'));
    // And access the body directly, which is typed as MyJsonData as requested.
    console.log(resp.body.someField);
  });
```